# Charm parameters configured at deployment

Tags: juju

I am creating a juju charm that needs to have parameters passed to the configuration upon deployment.

I have looked around and I know you can use `juju deploy <charm> --config="key:value;key2:value2"` but I cannot figure out where do those fit in to while creating the charm it self.

How can I do this and how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bruno, there is actually an open feature request right now for this capability:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/893184

You can create a yaml file right now that will set those options, this page explains it:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-config#configuring-an-application-at-deployment

Basically to do what your example talks about, save this as local.yaml:

```
service-name:
  key: "value"
  key2: "value2"
```

And then do

`juju deploy charm-name service-name --config local.yaml`

You can also set the options immediately after the deploy (before the unit is even running) with

`juju set service-name key=value key2=value2`

Comment: great! thx for the reply ;)